# SFP Reference Schematic Design

Tags: ethernet

I want to design a carrier board for NI sbRIO9607 mainboard, which has a gigabit ethernet port pinouts. However, I want to enlarge my system by SFP modules. Hence, I added a SFP Cage and SFP Connector into my carrier board design. However, I could not find a reference schematic design for SFP Connector.
You may find a SFP Module's related [SFP Host Connect Electrical Interface and Pins Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFXBq.png) by clicking the link. And you might find the [GBE Reference Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sIEt.png) by clicking this link.

Now, the question is, how can I put SFP instead of the GBE? Is there any reference schematic design for SFP connection or SFP to GBE conversion?

Thanks in advance.
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFP *is* a form of GbE, just without the PMD.

You can find all about SFP at snia.org, specifically in [INF-8074i](https://ta.snia.org/higherlogic/ws/public/document?document_id=1008). There's a schematic on page 23.

Note that the SFP interface uses single unidirectional lanes while 1000BASE-T, the "GbE" you're referring to, uses four bidirectional lanes. You'll need to access the GbE interface before -T PMD encoding.